# Postfix transport maps

Tags: email, postfix

I have 2 servers (A,B) with email server working. I am trying to replicate all emails sent to server A to server B using transport map. My transport table is

```
CREATE TABLE `transport` (
    `domain` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `transport` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    UNIQUE KEY `domain` (`domain`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I add row to that table to transport emails to server B it works

```
+-------------+----------------+
| domain      | transport      |
+-------------+----------------+
| example.com | smtp:[1.2.3.4] |
+-------------+----------------+
```

but when I try to add another server it stops working

```
+-------------+--------------------------------+
| domain      | transport                      |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
| example.com | smtp:[1.2.3.4], smtp:[2.3.4.5] |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

My question is, how to get it working? How can I get mails on two different servers replicated?

Comment: If you put a core routing table for postfix in a database like this, what happens when the database is down ?

Comment: Hi, I am very basic and according to few howto it should be done this way  [http://linux.justinhartman.com/Postfix_and_Courier_Installation_using_MySQL], do you know different solution for my problem?

Comment: I would strongly advise you not to follow random tutorials you find on the internet; most of them are plain wrong, or bad for general scenarios. Always use the **official postfix documentation** at http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 2):

[Transport maps](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) don't support multiple nexthops. You can try using [auto_bcc](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#auto_bcc) (or one of the BCC maps) to deliver mail to additional addresses.

For example, to deliver all mail destined for example.com to server B, create a domain for the "backup" mail (e.g. backup.example.com) and configure server B to accept mail for this domain. Then use a regular expression [recipient_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps) table which adds the counterpart user on backup.example.com as a BCC.

`main.cf`:

```
recipient_bcc_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
```

`recipient_bcc_maps`:

```
/^(.*)@example\.com$/   ${1}@backup.example.com
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, what I would like to is to have all emails  for example.com domain sent to server B and having copy on server A.

Comment: Updated answer with possible solution.

Comment: If, like me, you're lazy and only want to use one backup domain, add the domain part in the standard manner of `${1}=${2}@backup.example.tld`.